# How to write parallel loop iterations in one line (lists have unequal lengths)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
li1 = [['a','b','c'], ['c','d','e']]
li2 = [['c','a','b'], ['c','e','d']]
c = 1
for i in range(len(l11)):
    if (sorted[li1[i]]!=sorted(li2[i]):
        c = 0
if(c): k = True
else: k = False
```

How to write this in one line? Also how to use zip() to accomplish this?
What if `li2 = [['a','c','b']]`? Using zip would return True but it should give a False.

Comment: I have added the case where lists have unequal lengths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> zip(li1, li2)
<zip object at 0x0000000000723248>
>>> list(zip(li1, li2))
[(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'a', 'b']), (['c', 'd', 'e'], ['c', 'e', 'd'])]
```

and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
>>> all([True, True, True])
True
>>> all([True, False, True])
False
```

---

```
k = all(sorted(x) == sorted(y) for x, y in zip(li1, li2))
```